# v-slider выдает ошибку addEventListener onThumbMouseDown

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Никак не могу победить мою проблему.
Сразу скажу - vue вижу второй день.
Надо сделать калькулятор.
Использую v-slider от vuetify.
Если по слайдеру просто кликать - значения меняются.
Но если зажать мышь на thumb и попытаться перетащить ползунок - ничего не происходит.
В консоли получаю ошибку:

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
at onThumbMouseDown
```

Никаких наворотов с компонентом не делал.

Компонент:

```
<v-slider
id = "ceilingscale"
v-model="ceilingscale"
:max="255"
height="30"
></v-slider>
```

Сама страница расположена здесь:
http://germes.atmdenis.beget.tech/

Калькулятор и у него слайдер.
Одна отличительная особенность - input тоже должен быть завязан на слайдере.
Помогите разобраться.
Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

В общем отказался я от vuetify в пользу nightcatsama.github.io
Все очень быстро получилось